# Bigquery - Remove Duplicate using

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table where some records may be duplicates.

Table: dashboard.scrappy.imoveis
|    data   | imobiliaria | negocio | codigo | cidade |   uf   |  tipo  | bairro |   url  | endpoint | total | valor |
| --------- | ----------- | ------- | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | -------- | ----- | ----- |
| timestamp |    string   |  string | string | string | string | string | string | string |  string  | float | float |

Duplicate records are identified when they are the same in 4 columns (`data`, `imobiliaria`, `negocio`, `codigo`).

In the table there is no column with a row value index (incremental value).

I am trying to use the following instruction: (remove duplicates leaving 1 record)

```
DELETE FROM `dashboard.scrappy.imoveis`
WHERE ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `data`, `imobiliaria`, `negocio`, `codigo`) > 1) AND (COUNT(*) > 1 OR (COUNT(*) = 1 AND ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `data`, `imobiliaria`, `negocio`, `codigo`) = 1)))
GROUP BY `data`, `imobiliaria`, `negocio`, `codigo`;
```

But it is giving the error: Syntax error:
`Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword GROUP at [3:1]`

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you have to rewrite the query as we cannot use Group by in delete statement. Also aggregate/window functions cannot be used in where clause.

Easiest way to identify duplicates across all the columns is to run

```
'Select distinct * from table_name'
```

which will give you the unique rows.
you can store this result temporarily in a different table or replace the existing table:

```
create or replace table table_name as
select distinct * from table_name.
```

Or you can make use of with statement and delete the extra rows:

```
with cte as
(select *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `data`, `imobiliaria`, `negocio`, `codigo`) as dup_row from table_name )
delete from cte where dup_row > 1
```